# How to create android app which revtrieve video from website

Tags: android, android-layout, video, youtube, web

I have a website which contains some videos (all videos are uploaded on youtube). Now i want to make an android app for retrieving/watching videos from this site (like youtube). So, which kind of layout I should use for video objects? Can these videos be displayed same like on youtube?
Please give me some suggestions.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

yes you can, you have to work with youtube api for android so you can play the videos via youtube player here [youtube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) and you can download all of your videos using  a web service so you can access to your videos, you can you list view to show your videos, and you also can use custom list layout to make it more interested